# Error when fetching data from table using values from two different table - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables - "mfb_servicelog" and "mfb_agent_status_summary".

I want to select data from "total_ce" column in "mfb_agent_status_summary" where sl_id  = $sl_id and then export it as an excel sheet using PHPExcel.

I can get the $sl_id value from mfb_servicelog table where h_id = $value[$i].

And the values of $value is coming from another php file using _POST as an array.

Please point me to the right direection.

Here is my code: (Its returning long list of error)

```
$value = $_POST['hospitalname'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit") {
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($value); $i++) {
$queryslid="SELECT sl_id FROM mfb_servicelog WHERE h_id LIKE ('".$value[$i]."')";
if ($resultslid = (mysql_query($queryslid) or die(mysql_error())) {
                while($rowslid = mysql_fetch_row($resultid)) {
                    $slidset[$i] = $rowslid;
                }
                $querycasesentered = "SELECT total_ce FROM agent_summary WHERE sl_id LIKE ('".$slidset[$i]."')";
                if ($resultcaseentered = (mysql_query($querycasesentered) or die(mysql_error())) {
                    while($rowce = mysql_fetch_row($resultcasesentered)) {
                        $casee[$i] = $rowce;
                        if($i == 0) {
                            $col = 'H';
                        }
                        else {
                            $col = $k;
                        }
                        foreach ($rowce as $cell) {
                            $obejctPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
                            $col++;
                        }
                        $rowNumber++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem you're running into, exactly?

Comment: the problem is either its returning no result and no error or sometimes value as null whereas there are values present.

Comment: Have you used `JOIN` in SQL before? You can very easily use one query to return data from more than one table with that.

Comment: No..I am still in the learning phase.... No idea how to use that. @MariM

Comment: @PeeJay `JOIN` isn't too scary. I'd recommend taking a brief look through some tutorials on it, as I believe it'd greatly simplify your code.

Comment: Thank @MariM... I will definitely look into that. Lets see...I will keep you updated.

Comment: Can you add a few examples of the error? (Your life will become much easier with `JOIN`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a heads up, you are accepting POST data without cleaning it before running your SQL statement, this is very very dangerous and opens your database to injection attacts. But to the problem at hand.  Use a join SQL statement something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT total_ce FROM agent_summary AS agent LEFT JOIN mfb_servicelog AS service ON agent.sl_id = service.sl_id WHERE service.h_id LIKE ('".$value[$i]."')"
```

Comment: have you missed an "as" between agent_summary and agent?

Comment: @mbeintema No, it is nopt neccessary to use AS for a table alias, only for a column.

Comment: OKay... great.. I will let you know the result...thanks for the edit.

Comment: While the AS is not required, it still works with it in there, I have added it for readability sake, and edited in the "ON" clause which I originally had in the WHERE clause

Comment: I tried it on my database and its working... I will now add it on my php and run a test. Just one thing struck my mind... I have an existing query which returns some column values and export as an excel. Can I put this JOIN query inside that query. Here is my existing query :

Comment: $query="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(service_add_date, '%d/%b/%y'), DATE_FORMAT(scan_date, '%d/%b/%y'), DATE_FORMAT(ftp_date, '%d/%b/%y'),no_of_cases_reported,no_of_cases_received,case_count_diff, DATEDIFF(ftp_date, service_add_date) FROM mfb_servicelog WHERE h_id LIKE ('".$value[$i]."') AND service_add_date >= DATE_FORMAT('" . $from . "', '%Y-%m-%d') AND service_add_date <=  DATE_FORMAT('" . $to . "', '%Y-%m-%d')";

Answer (score 1):

You are using mysql_query in a wrong way.
mysql_query has 2 parameters which is the connection and the query

You can look at this definition:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

In short, I suggest that you should use PDO when you are not sure what you are doing with mysql. In order to understand what is PDO, you should read this tutorial http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers carefully which help you to prevent your code from the SQL Injection.

Comment: Thanks. I believe these tutorials will help me a lot understand the functions properly.

Comment: The last paragraph in this answer is good, recommending use of PDO. The first paragraph seems to be confusing `mysql_` interface functions (which are deprecated), with the newer `mysqli_` interface functions. I can't agree with the recommendation of the w3fools website. That's a mixed bag. Yes, there's a lot of useful information. The problem is that the good stuff is jumbled up with errors and misstatements. The errors aren't really the problem, the real problem is the utter failure of w3fools to correct the errors that are pointed out, and their failure to even respond to suggestions.

Comment: @spencer7593 thank alot. I link to w3schools at that time because I can not access the php.net website and I don't know why. It may be because of my internet connection.

Comment: @TruongHua: I've avoided w3schools for years. It seems that maybe things have improved. Anyone interested (but not familiar with) recent history can choose to visit the Internet Archive "Wayback Machine" to see an older copy of the w3fools website. [http://web.archive.org/web/20140531121518/http://www.w3fools.com/](http://web.archive.org/web/20140531121518/http://www.w3fools.com/).  (And who doesn't like visiting a website that uses "Wayback Machine", giving homage to a time-traveling dog and his pet boy.)